# apktool - extract process never finishes

Tags: java, android, apk, extract

When I try to extract `apk` file through [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) api, related extract process never finishes. **Same code works well for Java projects**. But when I use it inside Android application through virtual device, extract process never finishes.

Here is the code that I use:

```
ApkDecoder decoder = new ApkDecoder();
decoder.setApkFile(apkFile);
decoder.setOutDir(outputPath);
decoder.decode();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said on IRC.

> It **won't** work. There are 2 dependencies in Apktool that
>       won't work on Android. Yaml and some java 7 code.

Thats why it works fine on Java, but not in Android environment. [Bug](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=527) for java7 code, and the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=527) for Yaml.

Yaml is only used for parsing out the `apktool.yml` file, which is needed for recompile. Java 7 features were introduced for SmaliDebugging and NIO2 aids. If neither are needed, you could recompile the apktool binary without those two. (Of course then missing those features)

Comment: thanks a lot; so do you know any third party solution for this issue? @ConnorTumbleson

Comment: A third party solution to fix Apktool to work on Android? No... If I did, I would hope it would be pushed upstream into Apktool. There are the two bugs. Pull Requests are welcome :)

Comment: you're right; so does it mean that there is no solution to extract apk programmatically on Android? @ConnorTumbleson

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful for you: online version of the apktool is available here: www.javadecompilers.com/apktool

Hope, it would help you to decompile the application without installation of the numerous prerequisites.